# How do I update an object's state keeping the existing elements using useState hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I have an array of objects:

```
// seedColors.js

export default [
  {
    paletteName: "Material UI Colors",
    colors: [
      { name: "red", color: "#F44336" },
      { name: "pink", color: "#E91E63" },
    ]
  },
  {
    paletteName: "Flat UI Colors v1",
    colors: [
      { name: "Turquoise", color: "#1abc9c" },
      { name: "Emerald", color: "#2ecc71" },
    ]
  }
]
```

In my app.js file, I'm creating a new array of object, how would I append the new object to the existing object using useState hook?

```
// app.js

import seedColors from "./seedColors";

function App() {
  const [palettes, setPalettes] = useState({ palettes: seedColors });

  const savePalette = (newPalette) => {
    // newPalette = { paletteName: "New Test Palette", colors: [{ color: "blue", name: "blue" }] };
    setPalettes({ ...palettes, palettes: newPalettes });
  };
```

This isn't updating the original object state, instead it is crashing the application

I would want the state to be updated to:

```
[
  {
    paletteName: "Material UI Colors",
    colors: [
      { name: "red", color: "#F44336" },
      { name: "pink", color: "#E91E63" },
    ]
  },
  {
    paletteName: "Flat UI Colors v1",
    colors: [
      { name: "Turquoise", color: "#1abc9c" },
      { name: "Emerald", color: "#2ecc71" },
    ]
  },
  { 
    paletteName: "New Test Palette", 
    colors: [
      { color: "blue", name: "blue" },
    ] 
  },
]
```

Comment: `setPalettes({ ...palettes, newPalettes });`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, when I do this, it creates a new object outside the original array of objects.                                                                                                    
newPalette:
colors: (2) [{…}, {…}]
paletteName: "New Test Palette"
__proto__: Object
palettes: Array(2)
0: {paletteName: "Material UI Colors", colors: Array(2)
1: {paletteName: "Flat UI Colors v1", colors: Array(2)

Comment: Just to confirm, your current state value is not an array, and you want the updated one to be an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your application is likely "crashing" because you have a typo:

```
 setPalettes({ ...palettes, palettes: newPalettes });
 //                                             ^
```

You don't have a variable with name `newPalettes`. But even if you fix that, it doesn't produce the result you want.

Is there a reason you are setting the state to be an object with a single property? If not, just assign the array directly (which seems to be what you want based on your description of what you want the state to look like):

```
const [palettes, setPalettes] = useState(seedColors);
```

Then you can update the array with

```
setPalettes([...palettes, newPalette]);
```

---

If you need that object, then it would be:

```
setPalettes({...palettes, palettes: [...palettes.palettes, newPalette]});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that fixed it. I actually create the "newPalette" from another component and save it to the state. The last part of your answer worked (i.e palettes: [...palettes.palettes, newPalette])

Answer (score 1):

You declared `const [palettes, setPalettes] = useState({ palettes: seedColors });`
but you try to save as `setPalettes({ ...palettes, palettes: newPalettes });`

I would suggest to save them as on object:

```
const [palettes, setPalettes] = useState(seedColors);
setPalettes({ ...palettes, newPalettes });`
```